# Преобразовать дату в другой формат

Tags: java, дата, преобразование

У меня есть `Thu Aug 04 01-05-15 MSK 2022` — приходящая дата (приходит как строка)

Хотелось бы ее превратить в `04.08.2022 01-05-15`

*`01-05-15` - это время

дефисы оставил т.к. идет копирование файла и `:` не подходят при копировании*

Подскажите, какой метод следует выбрать, чтобы преобразовать данные в корректный формат?

Comment: какой метод?.. вы даже не сказали про какой язык программирования или про какую технологию идет речь

Comment: Сорри java ищу варианты метода Date

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String getCoolDate(Date date){
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh-mm-ss");
            return sdf.format(date);
        } catch (Exception exception){
            return null;
        }
    }

// логи
Thu Aug 04 12:15:15 GMT+03:00 2022
 
 04.08.2022 12-15-15
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким способом. Данные приходят как строка, поэтому есть сложности...

```
DateTimeFormatter newFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", new Locale("en", "EN") );
ZonedDateTime newDate = ZonedDateTime.parse( message.getSentDate().toString().trim(), newFormatter );
String month = String.valueOf(newDate.getMonthValue());
String year = String.valueOf(newDate.getYear());
String day = String.valueOf(newDate.getDayOfMonth());
String hour = String.valueOf(newDate.getHour());
String minute = String.valueOf(newDate.getMinute());
String second = String.valueOf(newDate.getSecond());
String date = day + "." + month + "." + year + " " + hour + "_" + minute + "_" + second;
```

Comment: Для форматирования тоже можно использовать DateTimeFormatter или SimpleDateFormat, посмотрите на мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1436086).

Answer (score 0):

Парсим дату:

```java
String input = "Thu Aug 04 23-05-15 MSK 2022";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH-mm-ss z y");
Date date = parser.parse(input);
```

Далее, форматируем:

```java
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.y HH-mm-ss");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

На выходе получим дату в формате:

```
04.08.2022 23-05-15
```